# What if I want to release an update with higher minSDK than the one on the market?

Tags: android, google-play

I have released [an app](http://fixedpointcode.blogspot.com) on the market with minSDK set to 4 (Android 1.6) but now I want to release an update with features unavailable in 1.6 so I need a higher minSDK.

So, my question is:
Will users running 1.6 be notified of this update?...and if yes will they be able to download/install it?

Comment: This is a question for http://stackoverflow.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you release an update, and the minimum sdk is say, android 2.0, I don't believe your 1.6 users will get info on the update, nor will they be able to install it because you state that it will not work on 1.6 devices.

They will, on the other hand, be able to keep the version they have installed.